# What are some experiments which prove the existence of quasi-particles in metals?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter

My interest here is to understand the following: The quasi-particle approach in say, Fermi liquid theory makes several predictions like temperature dependence of resistivity etc. which can be verified. I am wondering if there are some experiments which directly show us the existence of quasi-particles  in metals? In other words, is there any reason to not look for non quasi-particle description of ordinary metals?